# libraries conflict after adding in build.gradle

Tags: android, listview, instamojo

My app was worked fine until i added `instamojo` library in `build.gradle`

```
 dependencies {
        compile 'com.instamojo:android-sdk:+'
   }

    repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/godel-release/godel/"
    }

    maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"

        }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
```

**Stacktrace :**

```
Error:(308, 51) error: cannot access ListViewCompat
class file for android.support.v7.internal.widget.ListViewCompat not found
```

In class file,

```
cannot resolve method `getViewTreeObserver` at this line,
```

mReplacementPopup.getListView().getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

Comment: try to replace dependency with 'com.instamojo:android-sdk:1.0.5'

Comment: i have use  'com.instamojo:android-sdk:1.0.5' but same error given..

Answer (score 0):

listview is removed from android.support.v7.internal.widget.

You can find the same at android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.